# Difference between covariance and upcasting

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

What is the difference between covariance and upcasting, or, more specifically, why are they  given different names?

I've seen the following example referred to as 'upcasting':

```
string s = "hello";
object o = s;  //upcast to 'string' to 'object'
```

Whereas, the following I have seen called 'covariance':

```
string[] s = new string[100];
object[] o = s;

IEnumerable<string> ies = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> ieo = ies;
```

Now, to my untrained eye, covariance seems to be the same as upcasting, except that it refers the casting of collections. (And of a similar statement can be made regarding contravariance and downcasting).

Is it really that simple?

Comment: Jason's answer is pretty much spot on. For a more detailed explanation of the difference between covariance and assignment compatibility, see my article on the subject. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx You are not alone; lots of people get these two confused.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Cheers. Had I read that article before, i may never have posted this! Glad I did though. In truth, I was surprised there wasn't already a similar question like this on SO.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Now, to my untrained eye, covariance seems to be the same as upcasting, except that it refers the casting of collections. (And of a similar statement can be made regarding contravariance and downcasting).
>
> Is it really that simple?

Covariance isn't about upcasting, although I can see why you think it's related.

Covariance is about the following very simple idea. Let's say you have a variable `derivedSequence` of type `IEnumerable<Derived>`. Let's say you have a variable `baseSequence` of type `IEnumerable<Base>`. Here, `Derived` derives from `Base`. Then, with covariance, the following is a legal assignment, and an implicit reference conversion occurs:

```
baseSequence = derivedSequence;
```

Note that this is not upcasting. It is not the case that `IEnumerable<Derived>` derives from `IEnumerable<Base>`. Rather, it is covariance that allows you to assign the value of the variable `derivedSequence` to the variable `baseSequence`. The idea is that variables of type `Base` can be assigned from objects of type `Derived`, and since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in its parameter, objects of type `IEnumerable<Derived>` can be assigned to variables of type `IEnumerable<Base>`.

Of course, I haven't yet really explained what covariance is. In general, covariance is about the following simple idea. Let's say you have a mapping `F` from types to types (I'll denote this mapping by `F<T>`; given a type `T` its image under the mapping `F` is `F<T>`.) Let's say that this mapping has the following very special property:

> if `X` is assignment compatible with `Y`, then `F<X>` is assignment compatible with `F<Y>` as well.

In this case, we say that `F` is covariant in its parameter `T`. (Here, to say that "`A` is assignment compatible with `B`" where `A` and `B` are reference types means that instances of `B` can be stored in variables of type `A`.)

In our case, `IEnumerable<T>` in C# 4.0, an implicit reference conversion from instances of `IEnumerable<Derived>` to `IEnumerable<Base>` if `Derived` is derived from `Base`. The direction of assignment compatibility is preserved, and this is why we say that `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in its type parameter.

Comment: Thus far this is the only answer that actually explains the difference, so nicely done.

Comment: Yeah, wonderful answer, deserving at least as many votes as the question currently has. Hence the accept that I shall now perform.

Comment: ...That by no means denigrates the other answers, of course :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Casting** refers to changing the static type of *objects and expressions*.

**Variance** refers to the *interchangeability or equivalence of types* in certain situations (such as parameters, generics, and return types).

Answer (score 16):

`IEnumerable<string>` is not derived from `IEnumerable<object>`, so the cast between them is not upcasting.  IEnumerable is covariant in its type parameter and string **is**  derived from object, so the cast is allowed.

Comment: Since this is proving such a popular question, I was going to expand on this answer-- but I'll refer to @Jason's very good answer.

Answer (score 8):

The reason they are different concepts is that, unlike upcasting, covariance is not always allowed.  It would have been easy for the designers of the type-system to make `IList<Cat>` be considered as *"derived"* from `IList<Animal>`, but then we run into problems:

```
IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
IList<Animal> animals = cats; 
animals.Add(new Dog()); //Uh oh!
```

If this were allowed, now our `cats` list would contain a `Dog`!

In contrast, the `IEnumerable<T>` interface has no way of adding elements, so this is perfectly valid (in C# 4.0):

```
IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = cats;
//There's no way to add things to an IEnumerable<Animal>, so here we are ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Thie blog post below has a good explanation of it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather covariance removes the need for explicit downcasting subsequent to a previous upcast. Typically if you upcast an object you can only access the base type methods and attributes, with covariance it seems you can imply the downcast by replacing lesser derived types with more derived types in the more derived  class declaration.