# I know that generic arrays are not supported by Java, but I don't know how to fix this so it will work

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm try to create a HashTable and this part of the code requires an array, but when it's not delcared generic I get unchecked warnings, but I know that generic arrays aren't supported, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
array = new HashEntry<AnyType>[ nextPrime( arraySize ) ];
```

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is the canonical approach here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And being very careful.

Comment: @chrylis Or, preferrably, writing good tests for it :)

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366035/why-does-java-arraylist-use-per-element-casting-instead-of-per-array-casting helpful

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thorough tests are always good, but they won't prove a negative (lack of heap pollution).

Comment: @chrylis You can write tests which make every effort to cause heap pollution, and the test can definitely know when it has happened.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out JDK's own code for `HashMap`, specifically the `resize` method and these lines:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
        Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
```

`newTab` is then assigned to the main instance variable, `table`. So, if JDK can't avoid `@SuppressWarnings`, neither will you.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as such

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashEntry<K, V>[] array = new HashEntry[nextPrime()];
```

then add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to it.

Comment: When I do that, I get an identifier expected error @MJSG

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays. Use collections.

Using arrays requires more code, more care and gives no measurable benefit.

Using collections leverages the code and care built into the JDK.
If you've got an array of HashEntry, you're most of the way to a Map - just use a constant order map:

```
Map<SomeKey, SomeValue> map = new LinkedHashMap<SomeKey, SomeValue>();
```