# Base to Derived is possible(Boxing), But Derived to base gives run time exception, however that is equivalent to Unboxing

Tags: c#

Base to Derived is possible(Boxing). 
But Derived to base gives run time exception, however that is equivalent to Unboxing.
Why is it so

```
Base b = new Base();
Child c = new Child();
c = (child)b; // No compilation error but run time error

object a;
int i = (int)a; //No error Unboxing
```

Is it possible because object is top class all value type or Ref type inherited by Object class.
 public int ConvertToINT(object obj)
        {
            int i = (int)obj;
            return Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        }

Comment: you can undox only to type which was boxing

Comment: You still need to fix your code. You get a compile error if you just do `object a; int i = (int)a;`

Comment: Boxing is taking a value type (i.e. `int`/`float` etc.) and wrapping it as an object, you can't box an object that's already an object...

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing value boxing with reference casting.

If you do this:

```
int x = 1;
object a = x;
int i = (int) a;
```

Then the line `object a = x;` is boxing the integer value of x by (effectively) creating a wrapper class that contains the integer value `1`.

When you unbox it by casting it back to `int` the runtime code checks that its underlying type is correct (an `int`, because you are casting to `int`), and then it extracts the underlying value and assigns it to the target int variable.

If you do this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public int Value;
}

...

BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass d = (DerivedClass) b;
int myValue = d.Value; // What would happen? BaseClass doesn't have a Value property!
```

No boxing is involved here because we are working with reference types. Instead, this code is trying to treat a base class as if it was a derived class.

This is clearly impossible, because for example what would happen if you then tried to access `DerivedClass.Value`? This property doesn't exist in the base class, so it's impossible to treat an instance of the base class as a derived class.

Comment: Thank you Watson, But why static_cast is possible in C++

Comment: @user3007228 It's because not only does C++ allow you to shoot yourself in the foot, it lets you pretend that your head is your foot before you shoot yourself in it. (In other words, C++ doesn't do any runtime type checking for this; it just allows you to access memory that isn't part of the actual class, allowing all sorts of nastyness to occur. Mind you, it lets you do that with code that runs REALLY QUICKLY ;)

Answer (score 1):

from msdn [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type.

in your sample

```
Base b = new Base();
Child c = new Child();
c = (Child)b; // No compilation error but run time error
```

you create two different object and try cast it, this is not the same as

```
Base b = new Child();
Child c = new Child();
c = (Child)b; // No compilation error, no run time error if Child derived from Base
```

Answer (score 1):

I might get downvoted for this; but there is a way to *flirt* with dealing with higher derived objects; if that is what you want to accomplish. **This isn't up-casting**; this is ***Contravarience***; which allows you to call higher derived interface object so long as you don't require the T value to be returned at any time.

```
internal interface IVet<in T> where T : Animal
{
    void Set(T animal);
    void Heal();
}

class Animal
{
    public virtual void Examine(){Console.WriteLine("Animal");}
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void Examine(){Console.WriteLine("Cat");}
}

internal class Vet<T> : IVet<T> where T : Animal
{
    private T _value;

    public void Set(T animal)
    {
        _value = animal;
    }

    public void Heal()
    {
        _value.Examine();
    }
}
```

So you can do things like this

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IVet<Animal> _vetAnimal = new Vet<Animal>();
        IVet<Cat> _vetCat = _vetAnimal;

        _vetCat.Set(new Cat());
        _vetCat.Heal();
    }
}
```

Notice we have a `Vet<Animal>` object and we assign it to the contravarient interface `IVet<Cat>`. We can then use this interface to pass a 'Cat' variable and do something with it. So contravariance lets to you make the cast from `IVet<Animal>` to `IVet<Cat>`.

Useful is some circumstances; but again, not upcasting of a value... basically a wrapper where you can elevate the interface's generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding some OOP concepts. While it is true that you can use a derived class when the base class is required, you can not go the other way.

These work:

```
Base b1 = new Base();
Base b2 = new Child();
Base b3 = (Base)b2;
```

This does *not* work, as a `Base` simply is not a `Child`:

```
Base b1 = new Base();
Child c1 = (Child)b1;
```

To speak in the well know `Vehicle` examples:

While a truck is still a vehicle (every `Child` is also a `Base`), not every vehicle is a truck (not every `Base` is also a `Child`).

Comment: ... to make things more interesting, if you define `Base` as contravarient, I think you can upcast it. Although that one always trips me up, so I would need to check. :D

Comment: How would you do that in C#?

Comment: In a generic class with `<in TBase>` - but like I said; this one always trips me up.

Comment: @MeirionHughes covariance & upcasting aren't the same [thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707619/difference-between-covariance-and-upcasting).