# Cast Generic Object with getting type from Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, xamarin

I'm trying to cast an object in a generic object where I need to change the type dynamically.

`Dog<T>` inherits `Animal`, class "`T`" must inherit from `EntityBase`. For example, `Chihuahua` inherits `EntityBase`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++) {
    if (list?.ElementAt(i)?.GetType().GetTypeInfo().BaseType == typeof(Animal))
    {
        var type = list.ElementAt(i).GetType();
        // is wrong, must use a class no a type
        // var animal = list.ElementAt(i) as GenericObject<Dog<type>> 
        // Correct syntax but cast results null
        var animal = list.ElementAt(i) as GenericObject<Dog<EntityBase>> 
        // animal is null
        DoStuff(animal);
    }
```

If I use this code, it works:

```
if (list?.ElementAt(i)?.GetType() == typeof(Dog<Chihuahua>))
{   
    DoStuff(list.ElementAt(i) as Dog<Chihuahua>);
}
```

I want to do this as generically as possible, thanks a lot!

I will share the project I'm doing when I finish!

Comment: Please paste your code in as text. A screenshot of code isn't very useful.

Comment: You're looking for covariance.

Comment: Okey Thanks, I was on trying but the web stopped me with an error

Comment: Could you paste you **actual** code? What you posted have is full of errors.

Comment: Sorry, my code works on a much larger project, add the classes should be enough @DavidLively

Comment: @SLaks wow! With a quick glance think you're right, I'll try as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to have a single list hold different kinds of related types is called covariance (contravariance is also related).  This is achieved in .NET with the `out` and `in` keywoards respectively. With .NET 4.5, covariance is built into `IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented by `IList<T>`, which is implemented by `List<T>`.

If you have a list of `Animal`s, you can add any subtype of `Animal` to the list. However, when you get that animal out, in code, you get a variable of type `Animal` that points to your subtype of `Animal`. So it looks like you only have an `Animal` but it's really the subtype. You could try to manually cast everything as you suggested.

There is another workaround (.NET 4.5), you can use the `dynamic` keyword to have the type be determined at runtime. Then overload the `DoStuff` method, it should behave the way you want.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name;
    public Animal() { Name = "Animal"; }
}

public class Dog:Animal
{
    public Dog() { Name = "Dog"; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var list = new List<Animal>();
    list.Add(new Dog());
    list.Add(new Animal());
    foreach(dynamic a in list)
    {
        DoStuff(a);
    }
}

public void DoStuff(Animal animal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is wild", animal.Name);
}

public void DoStuff(Dog dog)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not wild", dog.Name);
}
```

This is the output

```
Test Name:  Test
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:  
Dog is not wild
Animal is wild
```

Covariance and contravariance is a complex topic. Check out these other posts.
[Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)
[Difference between covariance and upcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707619/difference-between-covariance-and-upcasting)

Comment: I did not know that. Very cool. It works the same with `List<Object>` instead of `List<Animal>`.

Comment: ...and of course, [it also works whether or not Dog inherits from Animal](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MNyL9Y).

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, using the dynamic keyword moves the topic away from covariance. Not sure how to classify it.

Comment: Well, it's overload resolution at runtime. But I don't know what a computer scientist would call it. To me it feels somewhat akin to pattern matching as in Scala/Swift/etc. Kinda sorta.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It works with List<object> because all classes inherit from object. You'll want to have an overload of DoStuff for object though.

Comment: The List works because all types inherit from object, certainly. And if you're throwing arbitrary pots and pans at it, naturally you'll want an Object overload as a backstop.

Comment: I don't understand why anybody isn't upvoting this answer. Am I the only one on Earth who didn't know that about `dynamic`?

Comment: Upvote thanks to @EdPlunkett's contagious enthusiasm for the answer.

Comment: As i promise here is the result! 
https://github.com/Danielbahe/PatternsSample 
I use it for disable xamarin Views

Comment: Covariance in C# is NOT the ability of a list to hold multiple types of object, but rather the ability of e.g. an `IEnumerable<Dog>` to also function as an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.