# "Generic" Type arguments / Inheritance in type arguments

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a function

`DoSomething(Dictionary<object, object> dict)`

why can't it be called with

`DoSomething(new Dictionary<int, string>())`?

Since `int`and `string` both inherit from `object`, I'd expect this to work. I know I could extend this to

`DoSomething<T1, T2>(Dictionary<T1, T2> dict)`

, but why won't the first option work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669858/simple-examples-of-co-and-contravariance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because a `Dictionary<int, string>` is not a `Dictionary<object, object>`.

For that to be true, the class type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` would need to be covariant in both `TKey` and `TValue`, and covariance would need to work with value types (boxing).

First of all, in .NET, generic *class* types are always invariant. Only interface types and delegate types can be co- or contravariant.

Secondly, a `Dictionary<,>` is not semantically covariant. For example you could say:

```
myDict.Add(new Elephant(), new BankCustomer());
```

and that would not be very pleasant if `myDict` was actually a (run-time) `Dictionary<int, string>` in a `Dictionary<object, object>` variable.

Now, since .NET 4.5, some of the "non-dictionary" types implement covariant interfaces like `IReadOnlyList<out T>`. You might hope that the similar interface `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` was covariant too. But it is not (the reason being given by the first comment by Servy below). So there is no hope for you.

Comment: `IReadOnlyDictionary` *must* be invariant with respect to `TValue` because `TryGetValue` uses it as an `out` parameter, which cannot vary in the type used.  `TKey` must be invariant because the key is used as input using `ContainsKey` and as output through `Keys`.  If `TryGetValue` had its signature changed so that `TValue` was only used in output then that generic argument could be covariant.

Comment: @Servy Absolutely! I mentioned your comment in the answer. Also note that in order for `IReadOnlyList<out T>` to be covariant in `T`, they had to omit the method `int IndexOf(T item);` which is otherwise present in list interfaces.

Comment: @Servy Upon thinking a bit more, I realize that what you very often do with a `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` is to `foreach` through it. There is the `GetEnumerator` method whose return type is also important for the variance here. For `foreach` to work, they would need to introduce some `IReadOnlyKeyValuePair<out TKey, out TValue>` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Just because `B` is a subtype of `A`, doesn't mean `List<B>` is a subtype of `List<A>` (or dictionaries, doesn't matter).

If it was, this would be legal at compile-time, but cause a runtime exception:

```
List<A> aList = new List<B>();
aList.Add(new C());
```

where C is a subtype of A.

For `X<B>` to be a subtype of `X<A>`, then `X<T>` would have to be covariant in its type parameter `T`.
For `X` to be covariant, `T` would have to be used *only* as the return type of its methods, but never as an argument.

Take `IEnumerable<T>` for example - this is a covariant interface.
`IEnumerable<string>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<object>`, because `T` is only used as a **return** type for `GetEnumerator`. So it's legal at both compile and runtime to do this:

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerator = new List<string>();
foreach(object o in enumerator)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```

More about covariance and contravariance in C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because `Dictionary` is invariant with respect to the types of both generic argument.

In C# *all* generic arguments are invariant.  Generic arguments can only be covariant or contravariant for interfaces.

The `IDictionary` interface also could not be covariant or contravariant with respect to either type argument.  Keys are passed out through the `Keys` property, in addition to being passed in...all over, and values are passed in using `Add` in addition to being passed out...all over.  Because both types are used as both input and output, the types *must* be invariant.

That, and covariance/contravariance will not work with value types; it can only work with reference types.

Just to provide a simple example, if you were allowed to make such a cast then I would be able to call `dict.Add("not an int", new Foo())` on the `Dictionary<object, object>`.  I've now added a key that's not an int and a value that's not a string.  Because allowing the cast would allow the use of types that don't match the signatures, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it because the type isn't covariant or contravariant in this way. Take this example:

```
var dict=new Dictionary<int,string>();
DoSomething(dict);

DoSomething(Dictionary<object, object> dict)
{
  var now=DateTime.Now;
  dict[now]=now;
}
```

In your scenario you've now added a `DateTime` to a dictionary of [int,string]!

Answer (score 0):

Simply because `Dictionary<T,Q>` is not covariant.

If it was possible then the following line would throw a runtime exception;

```
Dictionary<object, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["hello"] = new SomeOtherObject();
```

Since you would not be warned during build, you would end up with intermittent errors.