# There is no implicit reference conversion from... generic query handler cqrs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I want to create generic a query handler(and command handler in the future) which could handle each query and after processing, returns query result.

IQueryHandler interfaces:

```
public interface IQueryHandler
{

}

public interface IQueryHandler<TResult> : IQueryHandler
{
    TResult Execute();
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler
    where TResult : class 
    where TQuery: class
{
    TResult Execute(TQuery query);
}
```

IQuery inteface(which is marker interface):

```
public interface IQuery
{

}
```

Simple query object:

```
public class BrowseTitlesQuery : IQuery
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Simple query handler object:

```
public class BrowseTitlesQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<BrowseTitlesQuery, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Execute(BrowseTitlesQuery query)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

QueryBus

```
public class QueryBus
{
    public object Resolve<T>(IQuery query) 
        where T: IQueryHandler<IQuery, Object>, IQueryHandler, new()
    {
        return new T().Execute(query);
    }
}
```

And of course Program.cs class(I'm using console application to test)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bus = new QueryBus();
        var query = new BrowseTitlesQuery();

        bus.Resolve<BrowseTitlesQueryHandler>(query);

    }
}
```

In my opinion it should works but it doesn't. 
I have following error:

> The type 'cqrs.BrowseTitlesQueryHandler' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'QueryBus.Resolve(IQuery)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'cqrs.BrowseTitlesQueryHandler' to 'cqrs.IQueryHandler'. [cqrs]

Why is that?

Comment: why do you have 3 interfaces named "IQueryHandler"?

Comment: Only for tests, finally I want to have only single interface which will be the third from the list of above.

Comment: And if you refactor and leave only the third?

Comment: Nothing happens, the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with [co- and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669858/simple-examples-of-co-and-contravariance) here.

Let’s take a look at the covariance one first: `BrowseTitlesQueryHandler` implements `IQueryHandler<BrowseTitlesQuery, IEnumerable<string>>` so the return value from `Execute` is a `IEnumerable<string>`. However, in `QueryBus`, you are expecting a `T` of `IQueryHandler<IQuery, object>` with a return value of `object`.

In order to allow `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` to be cast down to `IQueryHandler<TQuery, object>`, the `TResult` parameter needs to be *covariant*. This is pretty simple here since it actually *is* a result, so making a it covariant is the right thing to do (note the `out`):

```
public interface IQueryHandler<out TResult> : IQueryHandler
{ … }

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, out TResult> : IQueryHandler
{ … }
```

The other problem is a bit more difficult and comes down to the fact that `BrowseTitlesQueryHandler` requires a `BrowseTitlesQuery`. But the `QueryBus.Resolve` will only give you a general `IQuery`. That’s not specific enough for `BrowseTitlesQueryHandler`.

Unfortunately, the only way to fix this is to make the query type a generic type argument for `Resolve` as well:

```
public object Resolve<T, TQuery>(TQuery query)
    where T : IQueryHandler<TQuery, object>, new()
    where TQuery : class, IQuery
{
    return new T().Execute(query);
}
```

Now, the `BrowseTitlesQueryHandler` gets the right query argument and can properly execute. Of course, you need to adjust your call then:

```
bus.Resolve<BrowseTitlesQueryHandler, BrowseTitlesQuery>(query);
```

Comment: It works, but I wanted to awoid passing query type as second T arg.
There is no another way to implement it without second generic arg, isn't it?

Comment: Not if you need your query handler to handle that exact type (instead of just `IQuery`). What you could do (maybe, if your application allows it) is make `QueryBus` generic with the handler as type argument and then have only the query type as an argument for `Resolve`. That way you would do `new QueryBus<BrowseTitlesQueryHandler>().Resolve(query)` (the generic query type argument will then be provided by the compiler using type inference). But that would of course restrict your query bus to a single handler type, so it may not be what you need.

Comment: At this moment I creates my query handlers just using 'new' operator, but in my opinion it's not so elegant, so I want to move instance's logic to query bus. If I used generic Query Bus I wolud to have to create instance of QueryBus by new operator, so in my opinion, the first solution which you have proposed is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the type parameters on your query bus:

```
public class QueryBus
{
    public object Resolve<THandler, TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query) 
        where T: IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>, IQueryHandler, new()
        where TResult : class 
        where TQuery: class
    {
        return new THandler().Execute(query);
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
bus.Resolve<BrowseTitlesQueryHandler, BrowseTitlesQuery, IEnumerable<string>>(query);
```

Comment: Yours solution works too, but this method seems to be too long. Have you any idea how it could be refactored?

Comment: It is only one type parameter longer. You could however create the THandler instance outside and pass it to the method. In this case the type parameters could be inferred and the call would be `bus.Resolve(handler, query);`